# Angular limitTo with filter return the limitTo size

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-limitto

I am trying to count the `rows` that remain after filtring:

```
ng-repeat="person in filtered = ( data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter} | limitTo:maxRowSize )"
```

And then use `{{ filtered.length }}` for the number of rows, but I get `maxRowSize` due to `limitTo`.
Is there a way to get `filtered.length` only without romoving `limitTo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple: exclude the `limitTo` like this:

```
ng-repeat="person in filtered = ( data | filter:query | filter : name | filter {m_resource: resourceFilter} | filter : {m_id : idFilter} ) | limitTo:maxRowSize "
```